# Salvar campos de uma pagina para outra

Tags: php, html

Tenho estas duas páginas cada uma com um formulário, gostaria de poder enviar em um email as informações dos dois formulários. Como faço para salvar os valores dos campos `nome` e `numero` e enviar apenas na pagina2 junto com os outros dois campos do form? Quero evitar enviar primeiro um email com as informações de pagina1 e depois enviar outro email com as informações da pagina2.

Pagina1.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Titulo</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
<body>
<form name="form" method="post" action="">
    Nome:
    <input type="text" name="nome">
    Numero:
    <input type="text" name="numero">
    <input type="submit" onclick="window.location.href='pagina2.html';">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Pagina2.html :

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Titulo</title>
</head>
<?php
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    ...
?>
<body>
<form name="form" method="post" action="">
    Endereço:
    <input type="text" name="end">
    Bairro:
    <input type="text" name="bairro">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neste caso você precisaria enviar por GET os dados da página 1 para página 2 e guardar em um hidden.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Titulo</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
<body>
<form name="form" method="get" action="pagina2.html">
    Nome:
    <input type="text" name="nome">
    Numero:
    <input type="text" name="numero">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

E na página 2

```
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Titulo</title>
    </head>
    <?php
        $nome = $_GET['nome'];
        $numero= $_GET['numero']       
...
    ?>
    <body>
    <form name="form" method="post" action="">
        Endereço:
        <input type="text" name="end">
        Bairro:
        <input type="text" name="bairro">
        <input type="hidden" name="nome" <?php echo "value='$nome'"; ?>>
        <input type="hidden" name="numero" <?php echo "value='$numero'"; ?>>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Depois é só submeter o form 2 e pegar $_POST["nome"] e $_POST["numero"] dele, que será o digitado no form 1.

Detalhe: se a página contém PHP, deve ter a extensão .php

Abraços!

Comment: A nível de curiosidade, existem outras maneiras de fazer isso?

Comment: Você pode fazer do jeito que ele disse, usando $_GET, ou também $_POST (o que funcionaria, mas teria o problema de o cara atualizar a página). Outra forma é usando cookies ou sessions, mas se o navegador do visitante não permitir cookies, não vai funcionar. Você também pode usar JavaScript de forma que todos os campos vão ficar na mesma página, e no mesmo formulário, daí quando ele passar da primeira parte, o JS oculta os campos da primeira parte e mostra os da segunda, com isso, é só fazer uma condição no JS dizendo que se o visitante estiver na parte 2, a ação do botão é enviar o formulário.